# How to detect multiple registration to the web from a single user

Tags: email, ip, limit, registration, account

use php and mysql,
My situation: users register to the web by entering username, email, password , birthday, sex and then activate account by clicking the link in their mails. Email and password are used in the log-in process.In database,I also record IP address and date-time of registration.
The problem is some users registered too much accounts to do something on the web as I limited one account per one click. The easy way is to check their IP address is existed or not, but in some academy organisation or company use the same IP address for all computers. 
**How to limit their registration and not to effect everyone who are those in the same ip address?**

Comment: ... you probably can't unless you can verify something unique about them, driver license #, etc.

Comment: Is there any unique for a single computer?

Comment: what if two users will use a single computer in your "academy organisation"?

Comment: That's the other condition too. TT

Comment: You can probably come up with some algorithm on your end and decide if you want to throttle their verification email. If user registers with same IP, similar or the same email, similar or the same password, etc. Then increase their suspicious-ness ranking during registration. Delay their registration or halt it if it reaches a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a way to block automatic registration. That's usually why you see the many registrations pattern. Robots crawl and register any site they find and can figure out.

I usually encode the FORM and use JS document.write() to print the form. Or use a hidden field filled by JS using and external obfuscated file. Or a CAPTCHA...

See if this does not fix your problem...

Comment: on registration page, it has the captcha. People who want to make more clicks inside the web ,that for member only and 1 account per 1 click, do it manually.